# Copy a row from one table to another

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to copy a full row of a table to another table, but every time i call this function it add a empty row on the t2(table 2)
why this the code isn't returning any value

**attempt**

```
def _copyRow(self):
    self.t2.insertRow(self.t2.rowCount())   
    columnCount = self.t1.columnCount()  
    for j in range(columnCount):
        if not self.t1.item(rowCount - 2, j) is None:
            self.t1.setItem(rowCount - 1, j, QTableWidgetItem(self.t1.item(rowCount - 2, j).text()))
```

Comment: Plesase provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to clone the QTableWidgetItem and insert it into the second table:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


def populate_table(table, prefix, rows, columns):
    table.clear()
    table.setColumnCount(columns)
    table.setRowCount(rows)
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("{} {}{}".format(prefix, i, j))
            table.setItem(i, j, it)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.spinbox1 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinbox2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Move")
        self.table1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()

        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.spinbox1, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.spinbox2, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.button, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.table1, 2, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.table2, 2, 1)

        populate_table(self.table1, "Table1", 3, 4)
        populate_table(self.table2, "Table2", 4, 3)

        self.spinbox1.setMaximum(self.table1.rowCount() - 1)
        self.spinbox2.setMaximum(self.table2.rowCount() - 1)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

    def handle_clicked(self):
        self.copy_rows(
            self.table1, self.spinbox1.value(), self.table2, self.spinbox2.value()
        )
        self.spinbox1.setMaximum(self.table1.rowCount() - 1)
        self.spinbox2.setMaximum(self.table2.rowCount() - 1)

    def copy_rows(self, from_table, row1, to_table, row2):
        if row1 >= from_table.rowCount():
            return

        if from_table.columnCount() > to_table.columnCount():
            to_table.setColumnCount(from_table.columnCount())

        if row2 >= to_table.rowCount() or row2 < 0:
            row2 = to_table.rowCount()

        to_table.insertRow(row2)

        for i in range(from_table.columnCount()):
            item = from_table.item(row1, i)
            if item is not None:
                to_table.setItem(row2, i, item.clone())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: it is possible to add the line with a doubleclick?

Comment: @PeterTorbenn I only implemented what the question asks for, I don't add more things every time the OP wants a new request, so I leave you as a task to do the double click thing. If you want to learn to use a tool then you must try, fail, try, etc. Bye. Also read [ask] and check the [tour]